# 2 mysql entries into different tables in one query?

Tags: php, mysql

I know how to enter information into one table, but how would I enter or take information from 2 different tables at the same time. I have researched and it has something to do with JOIN, but I have tried to no avail!

Comment: Why can't you use two queries? Just wondering.

Comment: I thought it was possible with JOIN, but it seems not, I can use 2 queries, I just thought it would be better not to to try and keep queries to a minimum?

Comment: less queries doesn't mean more performant. That is what all newbies think.

Comment: You can use a transaction to ensure that the data reaches both tables consistently. But you'd still need multiple mysql_query() calls for that.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! They have definetely helped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to insert into 2 tables in one query.

(Technically - you can create a trigger in table A, that inserts something to table B, but in this case you're not able to control what data to insert from the `INSERT`)